# How can I put 2 variables in countA in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to do something like

```
WorksheetFunction.CountA(target.address : target.address(0,2))
```

to count the number of non-empty cells for these 3 cells but it gives me an error.

One Way I can do is

```
WorksheetFunction.CountA(Target, Target.Offset(0, 1), Target.Offset(0, 2))
```

Are there any better ways?

One example is A1=3, A2 isempty, A3=4, the target.address is A1
The output I want by using countA in VBA is 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your target address is, for instance, "A1", and you want to look at a range 3 rows long and 1 column wide, you would say:

```
WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1").Resize(3, 1))
```